# ZF2 + Doctrine multiple connections issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have the following situation:

A ZF2 driven application which uses Doctrine for the database related stuff.
My directory layout is that of a typical ZF2 application, except that my module directory (the one that contains `src`) has a sub-directory `test` with a seperate module for testing the module in the parent folder.

```
├───MyModule
│   ├───config
│   ├───src
│   │   └───MyModule
│   │       ├───Controller
│   │       ├───DoctrineExtensions
│   │       ├───Entity
│   │       ├───Factory
│   │       │   └───ViewHelper
│   │       ├───Fieldset
│   │       ├───Filter
│   │       ├───Form
│   │       │   └───Element
│   │       ├───Helper
│   │       ├───Hydrator
│   │       │   └───Strategy
│   │       ├───Mail
│   │       ├───Model
│   │       ├───Service
│   │       ├───Traits
│   │       ├───Validator
│   │       └───View
│   │           └───Helper
│   ├───test
│   │   ├───doc
│   │   └───MyModuleTest
│   │       ├───data
│   │       │   ├───DoctrineORMModule
│   │       │   │   └───Proxy
│   │       │   └───sql
│   │       │       └───data_single
│   │       ├───Fixture
│   │       └───Service
│   └───view
│       ├───flash-messenger
│       └───partial
```

I want to use a seperate Doctrine configuration and DB connection so I set it up according to [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#how-to-use-two-connections) documentation.

In the `Bootstrap.php` file I use for setting up loading the modules under test (gets loaded by PHPUnit before every test run) I set up the ZF2`s ServiceManager and load the Doctrine configuration.

```
static::$config = $config; // contains merged config
$serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
$serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
$serviceManager->setFactory('ServiceListener', 'Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceListenerFactory');
```

But when I try to get the entity manager

```
$em = $serviceManager->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_testing_mysql');
```

I  always get a

*RuntimeException: Options with name "orm_testing_mysql" could not be found in "doctrine.entitymanager"*

Running my debugger I found out that `$serviceManage->instances['applicationconfig']` contains all the arrays I defined in my configuration file.
`$serviceManage->instances['config']['doctrine']` however only contains the default doctrine configuration / connection data shipped with the module.

Can someone figure out what's going wrong?
Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

```
     use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
        use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfiguration;

        class Bootstrap

    {
        protected static $application;

        public static function init()
        {

            chdir(dirname(__DIR__ . '/../../../../../')); // <-Project path

            include __DIR__ . '/../../../../init_autoloader.php'; //<- ur init_autoloader.php

            self::$application = \Zend\Mvc\Application::init(include 'config/application.config.php');
        }

        public static function getServiceManager()
        {
            return self::$application->getServiceManager();
        }
        public static function getEntityManager()
        {
        return self::getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        }
```

Then When you use in to open connection with ORM

```
setUp()
{
    $this->service = Bootstrap::getServiceManager()->get('ServiceRoute')
}
```